How do I disable Astro from adding scripts and styles in a layout?
I'm adding an email template page to my Astro site that needs it's own very specific styles (and no scripts) but Astro is injecting the site styles and scripts into this layout.
/pages/email/[...slug.astro]
---
import { getCollection } from 'astro:content'

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const blogEntries = await getCollection('posts', ({ data }) => {
    return import.meta.env.PROD ? data.draft !== true : true
  })
  return blogEntries.map(entry => ({
    params: { slug: entry.slug },
    props: { entry },
  }))
}

const { entry } = Astro.props

---

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>{entry.data.title}</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; background-color: #F3EFE7;">
    <h1 style="margin: 0 0 10px; font-size: 25px; line-height: 30px; color: #333333; font-weight: normal; font-family: serif;">{entry.data.title}</h1>
</body>
</html>


When I view the source in dev mode all the tailwind styles are getting included as well as the different module scripts.  When I build the page they still get included as links in the head
<link href=/_astro/index.B-4v29RP.css rel=stylesheet>
<script src=/_astro/page.D7oTWwjY.js type=module></script>

Presumably these are from the integrations in my Astro config but how do I disable them for one specific layout?

Not sure if there's a better way, but you could write a middleware, parse the response's HTML and remove the stuff you don't want.
